# The easiest way to convert multi-digit char to integer

Tags: c, char, integer

Let's say here is a char with unknown digit number in C:

```
char char_id[1000] = {'1', '2', '3', ..., '8', '9', '\0'};
```

If I want the last two digit to form an integer i.e. '89'.

What is the easiest way?

Comment: first, Delete `'/0'` or replace with `'\0'`. Then Use `strlen` and such as `atoi`.

Comment: `char num[1]; int len = strlen(char_id); sprintf(num, "%c%c", char_id[len-1], char_id[len]);`

Comment: @Gaurav It's very bad.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why? what happened? The index is not right it should be `sprintf(num, "%c%c", char_id[len-2], char_id[len-1]);`

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Gaurav It's still wrong. 1) `char num[1];` is too small. 2) OP want _convert multi-digit char to integer_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ohh, :-( Yes the array is small. From the question, it seems that OP wants to concatenate two chars as he has written 89 in single quotes '89'.

Comment: `Let's say here is a char`..wait!! STOP!! a `char` and a `char` array are not the same things!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh I got it!

Comment: @Gaurav well, that was more meant for the OP, but welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can simply use `atoi` function.
  `size_t pos = strlen(char_id);`

`int num = atoi(&char_id[pos-2]);`

Or simply

`int num = (char_id[pos-2]-'0')*10+(char_id[pos-1]-'0');`

<sup>The first solution uses ASCII encoding- which makes thid solution not potable across different platforms.</sup>

- Use the `null` character. `\0`.
- If it is digit then you can easily the second way shown over here.

Comment: `int num = atoi(char_id[pos-2])*10+atoi(char_id[pos-1]);` --> `int num = atoi(&char_id[pos-2]);`

Comment: It's still wrong. Please note that `atoi` does not convert single letters. (I haven't downvote, yet.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Here atoi is overrated But yes..we can do this. Check once

Comment: @Stargateur.: Oh...I missed. Check once..thanks for pointing out

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya digit - '0' is portable.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In C, character from `'0'` to `'9'` are mandatory to be contigus.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya.: Yes this is not protable. ASCII encoding is most common though...but I will add it. Check once..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.: Multitasking is really a problem at times.. But thanks for pointing the error.

Comment: @Stargateur, Ah yes. Removed the comment. Thanks

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The C standard guarantees that digits are consecutive.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, I realised my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to take the two last (non NUL) chars and convert them to a `int` variable. Can be done in many ways:

Here is one way:

```
int main(void) {
    int n;
    char char_id[1000] = {'1', '2', '3', '8', '9', '\0'};
    size_t len = strlen(char_id);
    if (len >= 2)
    {
        n = atoi(&char_id[len-2]);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("string too short\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
89
```

An alternative conversion could be:

```
n = strtol(&char_id[len-2], NULL, 10);
```

Comment: not important but you should move `int n = 0;` directly where you call `atoi()` => `int n = atoi(&char_id[len - 2]);` and maybe advice to use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()`

Comment: @Stargateur - I added `strtol` an another option

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple function to convert string to int.

```
int str2int(char *numStr)
{
    int intVal=0 ;

    while(*numStr != '\0')
    {
        intVal *= 10;
        intVal  += *numStr - '0'; //0x30 ascii value of charater 0
        numStr++;
    } 
    return intVal;
}
```

To convert last 2 digits you can pass address of that digit for e.g &char_id[5]

Answer (score 2):

may be this

```
char char_id[1000] = {'1', '2', '3', /*..., */ '8', '9', '\0'};
int what_i_want    = atoi( char_id + ( strlen(char_id) - 2 ) );
```

by the way those dots are a bit of rubbish,  comment them

Answer (score 0):

You have your entire number stored as a string in `char_id`.

You need to first get the start of the string where you want the number from.

Since you want the last two digits, a simple way would be -

```
char *sub_string = char_id + (strlen(char_id) - 2);
```

This assumes that there is a `\0` at the end. If you dont have have that, but know that the entire array is filled you can use `sizeof(char_id)`.

Now you need a robust way to extract the integer stored.
I would suggest using `sscanf`.

```
int number;
if(sscanf(sub_string, "%d", &number) != 1) {
     printf ("Invalid number in string");
     // Exit?
}
printf("Number scanned = %d\n", number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this function.

```
int char_to_int(char *ptr, int length)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(length--)
    {
        sum += (pow(10, length) * ((*ptr++) - 48));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You should use like that

```
...
int number = char_to_int((char_id + 7), 2);
...
```